# Facebook api giving empty result for like sources for Jan 20 and 21 of 2014

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I have created an app for page insights data analysis.I am capturing insight data for everyday.But when i checked my database there is no data for like sources for 4 days Jan 19,20,21,22. So i run the capturing script again and then i got data for 19 and 22 .Then i checked graph api console and there is no data for 21,22.I checked for around 20 pages , all has the same issue.Why this happend.Is there any issue from facebook.Please help me to find the actual reason for this.

Thanks 
Azeez

Answer (score 0):

yes it appears to be an issue with Facebook API since January 16

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/trending/